# Hydrogen wave function stationary state

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, hydrogen

> An electron in a hydrogen atom at an instant $t=0$ have the following wave function:
>   $$\Psi(r,\theta,\phi,t=0)=\frac{1}{2}R_{1,0}(r)Y_0^0(\theta,\phi)+\frac{i}{\sqrt{2}}R_{2,1}(r)Y_1^0(\theta,\phi)+\frac{1}{2}R_{3,2}(r)Y_2^1(\theta,\phi)$$

Is $\Psi(r,\theta,\phi)$ an stationary state? Why?

It will stationary just because does not depend on time, or will be necesary another condition?

Comment: Homework assignent? Start reading the book.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because there is no evidence of prior effort or research.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get the wave function at arbitrary time t. Then calculate Magnitude of w.f by multiplying by its cc. If it does not depend on time it is a stationary state.

Comment: This is true as far as it goes and is a working procedure; but there is a much easier way to answer the question (and it sets you up for thinking of quantum mechanics in terms of abstract states and eigenvalues which is advantageous when moving on from the Schrödinger picture).